# how can I add UIImages to my PFFile array so that if query for a PFFIle images fails, it can be replaced by appending an UIImage?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, parse-platform, uiimage

retrieving  images from Parse and showing them on a tableView, if I scroll the tableView down, app crashes and gives me "fatal error: Array index out of range"

numbers of rows is given by the number of messages in "messagesArray"

I think the problem is that in the query, if I don't find images in pointers, I say "append to the `PFFile` array this standard `UIImage` of mine called "logo" " so when I scroll down, count of imagesArray and messagesArray doesn't mach.

**how can I add UIImages to my PFFile array so that if query for a PFFIle images fails, it can be replaced by appending  a UIImage?**

some told me to make a separate query for the image it in     `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {}`

but the main query is called itself that way.

I have this array:

```
var picturesArray : [PFFile] = []
```

in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I have:

```
self.picturesArray[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (imageData: NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil {
                let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                cell.senderProfileImage?.image = image

            } else {

                print("plan B")
                cell.senderProfileImage?.image = UIImage(named: "logo")

            }

        }
```

in my query, I can retrive the names of my senders by querying a "sender" column with pointers to `_Users`. I have:

```
if let theName = singleObject.objectForKey("sender")?.objectForKey("first_name") as? String {
                        // this retrieves names from pointer "sender" in "Messages"
                        self.sendersArray.append(theName) //populate the array with names
                    } else {
                        if let messageSender = singleObject["senderNickname"] as? String {
                            self.sendersArray.append(messageSender)
                        }
                    }

                    if let profilePicture = singleObject.objectForKey("sender")?.objectForKey("profile_picture") as? PFFile {

                    self.picturesArray.append(profilePicture)

                    } else {
                        //I think this is the problem:
                        print("no image found in pointer to users")
                        self.picturesArray.append(UIImage(named: "logo"))
                    }
```

Solution:

for now, is also required fix [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32761042/swift-app-transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http-resource) bug (hoping Apple and Parse will take care of them sooner or later)

```
//very new, it's ok
                    if let theName = singleObject.objectForKey("sender")?.objectForKey("first_name") as? String {
                        // this retrieves names from pointer "sender" in "Messages"
                        self.sendersArray.append(theName) //populate the array with names
                    } else {
                        if let messageSender = singleObject["senderNickname"] as? String {
                            self.sendersArray.append(messageSender)
                        }
                    }



                    //very new : this fix fatal error: Array index out of range
                    if let profilePicture = singleObject.objectForKey("sender")?.objectForKey("profile_picture") as? PFFile {

                    self.picturesArray.append(profilePicture)

                    } else {
                        //I think this is the problem:
                        print("no image found in pointer to users")
//                        self.picturesArray.append(UIImage(named: "logo"))
                        let imageData:NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIImage(named: "logo")!)!
                        self.picturesArray.append(PFFile(data: imageData))
                    }
```

and

```
 //this fixes the crash related to different number of rows and images
        if indexPath.row < picturesArray.count {
            self.picturesArray[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (imageData: NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

                if error == nil {
                    let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                    cell.senderProfileImage?.image = image
                }

            }
        } else {
//            cell.senderProfileImage?.image = UIImage(named: "logo")
            print("no foto!")
        }
```

Comment: Is your code crashing in this line `self.picturesArray[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (imageData: NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in` ?

Comment: yes, it seems so! gives fatal error: `Array index out of range`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app is crashing because you have more table view cells than pictures in picturesArray

Just check if indexPath.row <  picturesArray.count before using picturesArray[x]

```
if indexPath.row < picturesArray.count {
    self.picturesArray[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (imageData: NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
            cell.senderProfileImage?.image = image
        }

    }
} else {
    cell.senderProfileImage?.image = UIImage(named: "logo")
}
```

#### Edit:

If you want to append a PFFile with the logo image into picturesArray you can do the following

```
let imageData:NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIImage(named: "imagename")!)!
self.picturesArray.append(PFFile(data: imageData))
```

instead of

```
self.picturesArray.append(UIImage(named: "logo"))
```

#### Explanation:

Here `self.picturesArray.append(UIImage(named: "logo"))` you were trying to add an `UIImage` object to and array that only accepts `PFFile` objects, as you declared here: `var picturesArray : [PFFile] = []`

You need to instantiate a new `PFFile` and add an `UIImage` to it, but the `PFFile` initialiser only accepts `NSData` to store.

So to transforma an `UIImage` into `NSData` you can use `UIImagePNGRepresentation` and then instantiate the `PFFile` with the image data.

Comment: you mean in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` ??

Comment: Yes, inside cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: ok, this fixes the crash, but now, I have always the image of the same user, do you know how can I append the default UIImage to the piffle array? this could kill the issue

Comment: I have :  `Cannot convert value of type 'UIImage?' to expected argument type 'PFFile' ` after ""no image found in pointer to users""

Comment: I edited my answer, check if this solves your problem

Comment: great! everything seems to be working! question answered! While I update question and mark it as answered, could you fully explain to me your last solution? how does it work `UIImagePNGRepresentation` ? I was trying to apply UIImage(image) but failed:( thanks!

Comment: Edited again, see if you understand the explanation and sorry for my bad english haha

Comment: everything's clear, let's leave it there for user's future reference :)